# What is the correct order in these sentence? (Passive voice)

Tags: passive-voice

There are French history, traditions, culture and famous people described. OR There are French history described traditions, culture and famous people. 
Please help me:)

Comment: Neither of these sounds happily English to me, I'm afraid. I'm not sure why, but think it's to do with the way you have split _are_ from _described_. It's hard to know what else you might say without knowing the context, or why you want the passive voice. Is everything in your list French?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your intention.

> There are French history, traditions, culture and famous people described.

e.g. written as *There are descriptions of French history, traditions, culture and famous people.*

This states French

- history
- traditions
- culture
- famous people

are described.

You may also take the *French* solely for *French* history, some traditions etc.

---

> There are French history described traditions, culture and famous people.

e.g. written as *There are traditions, culture and famous people described by French history.*

This one states there is a description by French history of the other list items.